# 12v switching ChipFet with a 3V gate?

Tags: mosfet

The title may seem ridiculous, but I am unable to find a ChipFet that has a 3V gate, and can switch 12V, I am unable to provide 5V to the gate. Are there any well known SMD small and compact Mosfets that can be activated with 3V/3.3V? Thanks!

Comment: How much current ?

Comment: you might have to cascade them.  ALD101x series has a threshold of about 1V, if I recall

Comment: Each 'Fet will switch a 3W LED, in a tricolour Led. its less then an amp.

Comment: Checking http://www.vishay.com/mosfets/chipfet-package/ 
- most of the single FET are specified for 2.5V or even 1.8V on the gate and are able to drive several Amps. All can stand a Vds and Vgs of at least 12V.

Comment: IRLML2502 has max 0.08 Ohms Rdson at Vgs= 2.5V

Comment: Most of these have a Vgs(th) of about 1V. http://www.vishay.com/mosfets/chipfet-package/

Answer (score 1):

Use another FET, probably a N-Channel to switch the larger P-FET on and off. This topology is called a load switch:

[image]

Select R2 first, around 100ohm to 1Kohm, and R1:R2 need to be in a 1:10 to 1:100 ratio. Q1 being a logic-level N-MOSFET, and C1/R2 providing a slew rate limiter. R1 pulls Q2's gate to the bus voltage, and when Q1 turns on it pulls Q2's gate to ground, turning the switch on. Only Q2's S-D sees any significant load.

Also this isn't intended to be switched from PWM, it's more of a "power-on/power-off" application switch.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put R2 in series with the drain of Q1 instead of the source?

Comment: It wouldn't really make a difference. How do you see it as better? You could really just forego C1 and R2 altogether, they are there to limit inrush current.

Comment: You don't think that the voltage drop across R2 has any effect on the gate voltage required?

Comment: Not with an enhancement mode logic level gate MOSFET. They typically are fully on with around 2.5v on the gate (or less), no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of such MOSFETs, though maybe not "ChipFET", which I think is a Vishay type.

Eg. [DMN2075U](http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/ds31837.pdf) from Diodes Inc, which is 45m\$\Omega\$ maximum Rds(on) with only 2.5V drive.

If you drive a 2.5V-rated MOSFET with 3V it will have a lower Rds(on) than it will at 2.5V.

Edit:

Looking specifically at **single ChipFET N-channel MOSFETs**, suitable for the voltage and drive, I see one: [Si5432DC](http://www.vishay.com/docs/68925/si5432dc.pdf). It's got only 25m\$\Omega\$ Rds(on) with 2.5V drive, though given the price and availability I think I would prefer the one I mentioned above.